# $u_n = \int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \sin(nx)\,dx$ converges

Tags: integration, limits, proof-verification

I would like to prove that the sequence :

$$u_n = \int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \sin(nx) \,dx, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
 is convergent without calculating the antiderative of the function : $$x \rightarrow (x-1) \cdot \sin(nx)$$

Here is what I've done :

Notice that : $$u_n = \int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \sin(nx) \,dx = \int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \frac{1}{n}\cdot (-\cos(nx))'\,dx = \frac{-1}{n} \int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \cos(nx)' \, dx$$
and $1/n \rightarrow 0$ and because $\int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \cos(nx)'$ is a finite number (it represent the area of acontinuous function on a close interval) then $u_n = 0$.

I was wondering if my attempt is good because the equality : 
$$\int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \sin(nx)\,dx = \int_0^\pi (x-1)\cdot \frac 1 n \cdot (-\cos(nx))' \, dx$$
doesn't seem natural to me...

Comment: The more problematic point is that $\int_0^\pi(x-1)\cos(nx)'\mathrm dx$ depends on $n$

Comment: Thank you for answering, I must say that I don't understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: This is a consequence of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma. One gruesome way would be to partition $[0,\pi]$ into periods of $x \mapsto \sin (nx)$ and use uniform continuity (approximating $x-1$ by the left value, for example) to show that the result is zero.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Does $\cos(nx)'$ mean the derivative of $\cos(nx)$?  If so then this is $-n\cdot\sin(nx)$ and you have just hidden the $n$.

Comment: Yes : $cos(nx)'$ mean the derivative of $cos(nx)$, but then what I did is false ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't help since it grows with $n$ and cancels out the $1/n$.

Comment: @badjohn What you are saying is false : $\int_0^\pi (x-1) \cdot (cos(nx))' dx$ is a constant number

Comment: Constant for one particular $n$ but I expect that it varies with $n$.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't vari that much because for all $n, -1 \leq \cos(nx) \leq 1$ hence : $\int_0^\pi (x-1) \cdot (\cos(nx))'dx < (\pi^2/2)$

Comment: $-1 \leq cos(nx) \leq 1$ is true but $-1 \leq (cos(nx))' \leq 1$ is not.  What's the derivative of $cos(nx)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) we instantly have $\lim_{n\to +\infty} u_n = 0$.

As an alternative,

$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1}(x-1)\sin(nx)\,dx = \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n}\left(\frac{x}{n}-1\right)\sin(x)\,dx $$
and $\sin(x)$ has a bounded primitive, hence it is enough to show that 
$$ \frac{1}{n^2}\int_{0}^{n}x\sin(x)\,dx \stackrel{IBP}{=} \frac{1}{n^2}\left[n(1-\cos n)-\int_{0}^{n}(1-\cos x)\,dx\right] $$
is convergent to zero, but that is trivial.

Comment: That's a nice way to solve the problem :) Yet what I did is false or it works ?

Comment: @J.OK: your manipulations are not wrong, but they are quite ineffective: the term that is screaming for differentiation is $x-1$, not $\sin(nx)$.

Answer (score 0):

With integration by parts, 
$$\int_0^\pi f(x) \sin(n x) \, dx = \left. - \frac1n f(x) \cos(n x) \right|_0^\pi + \frac1n \int_0^\pi f'(x) \cos(n x) \,dx.$$

You could also argue that $\left| \int_a^{a + h} \sin(n x) dx \right| = \mathcal{O}(h / n)$, and approximate $f$ by a piecewise constant function.

Comment: I know I can use IPP yet I have to prove that it converges without calculating the antiderivative of the function...